# Liferay overriding other domains

Tags: apache, liferay

My question is simple, though the answer eludes me.
I want to have 4 sites running.

- htmlsite1.com
- htmlsite2.com
- htmlsite3.com
- portalsite.com

htmlsite1.com is my default Apache server, while sites 2/3 are virtual servers. I want the portal to run off of a separate virtual server. I decided to use Liferay 6.1 for the portal, and my HTML sites were through Apache.
The HTML sites were up and running before installing Liferay.

My Issue:
Since installing Liferay, all of my websites redirect to the Liferay home tree.

My question is: Can I run standard HTML pages while using Liferay?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure which part of the situation is unclear for you. I assume that all content is served through Apache, but portalsite.com is just proxied by apache, then relayed to Liferay.

Assuming your portal runs on tomcat or another appserver that supports "AJP", read about `mod_jk` and how to use it to relay traffic to your portal. You'll end up with a configuration for a virtual host that is somehow similar to this (pseudo-code-configuration, only typed here, never tested, beware the typos...)

```
 # external "workers" configuration file for mod_jk, defining 
 # connection properties for 
 JkWorkersFile /path/to/your/jk/configuration

 <VirtualHost *:80>
     ServerName portalsite.com
     # all content should be forwarded to tomcat...
     JkMount /* your_tomcat_worker
     # ...except the content in the /static directory, which should be 
     # served by Apache directly, without involving tomcat
     JkUnMount /static/*
 </VirtualHost>
```